# Introducing text and displaying block versus inline

Tags: css

I have a while loop that echos out several images. My next step is to have text over the image. However, as soon as I add that text to the while loop my images go from inline to block. I've tried just about everything from changing the display to inline and playing with the different positions with the images and text. How do I fix this. Code below.

Script Section

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {

$("h2")
    .wrapInner("<span>")

$("h2 br")
    .before("<span class='spacer'>")
    .after("<span class='spacer'>");

});
</script>
```

Style Section

```
<style type="text/css">

body {height: 1100px;}
html {height:1200px; }

h2 { 
   top: 200px; 
   left: 25px; 
   width: 100px; 
  position: relative;
}

div #image_box {width: 700px; display:inline;}

img {border: 1px solid grey; padding: 0; margin:15px; display:inline;}

#viewers_pleasure { padding: 15px; height: 1200px; width: 4800px; }

h2 span { 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 10px; 
}

h2 span.spacer {
padding:0 5px;
}
</style>
```

Body Section

```
<div id="viewers_pleasure">

<div id="image_box">
<img src="images/89c246298be2b6113fb10ba80f3c6956_8" width="560" height="420"/>    
<h2><br>$</h2>
</div>

<div id="image_box">
<img src="images/8e73b27568cb3be29e2da74d42eab6dd_9" width="560" height="420"/>
<h2><br>$</h2>
</div>

<div id="image_box">
<img src="images/216e77337cdef3bd1bede845d1aba608_3" width="560" height="420"/>
<h2>weezer<br>$0</h2>
</div>

<div id="image_box">
<img src="images/452ff601eb791947cd76a2119f1db973_2" width="560" height="420"/>    
<h2><br>$</h2>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Don't need to see the PHP, just the HTML.  Please post the output.

Comment: what is the use of "<div class="image"></div>" if nothing is coming, check your div placements

Comment: first of all your while loop condition i guess should be while($x<5) and the $x variable should be incremented in the while loop. $x++

Comment: Sorry about the php. First time posting on the CSS section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using float left for image_box

```
div #image_box {width: 700px; display:inline; float:left }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the `<h2>` tags are `display:block` by default.  Try removing them from the flow  and see if fixes the image display issue.

Comment: the image is still displayed as a block.